# Access instance variable of dumped headers (iOS)

Tags: ios, theos

I want to know the value of "_lastNotificationReceivedBundleIdentifier" which is an instance variable of a class. The header is dumped from iOS springboard app.

```
@interface SBRemoteNotificationServer : NSObject <APSConnectionDelegate> {
    NSMutableDictionary* _bundleIdentifiersToClients;
    NSMutableDictionary* _environmentsToConnections;
    unsigned _lastPlayedAlertSound;
    NSString* _lastNotificationReceivedBundleIdentifier;
}
```

but the following code does not work:

```
%hook SBRemoteNotificationServer
-(void)noteApplicationFinishedLaunching:(id)launching{
    NSLog(@"identifier=%@",_lastNotificationReceivedBundleIdentifier);
    %orig;
}
%end
```

and the compiler error is:

```
error: ‘_lastNotificationReceivedBundleIdentifier’ was not declared in this scope
```

How do I access and log this NSString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use the objective-c runtime capabilities and take a look at the method `object_getInstanceVariable(the_object, "_lastNotificationReceivedBundleIdentifier", (void**)&yourPointer);`

Comment: Thank you. the method object_getInstanceVariable works:

`-(void)noteApplicationFinishedLaunching:(id)launching{
    NSString *str;

    object_getInstanceVariable(self, "_lastNotificationReceivedBundleIdentifier", (void **)&str);

    NSLog(@"identifier=%@",str);

    %orig;
}`

Comment: Yay! You can flag my answer as correct so that in the future if someone is searching for the same problem he will know where to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to try is:

```
[self valueForKey:@"lastNotificationReceivedBundleIdentifier"];
```

where `self` is the parent object and `lastNotificationReceivedBundleIdentifier` is the variable name. eg same as `self.lastNotificationReceivedBundleIdentifier`.